# Nginx Windows Proxy Cache server static content

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

Basically i am trying to setup nginx with apache but i want nginx to serve static content such as javascript, stylesheets, media files etc but i want php to be passed to apache listening on port 8080.

Using the following i can get nginx to redirect php requests to apache listening on port 8080

```
location ~ \.php$ {
proxy_pass         http:127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

But how can i tell nginx to serve all static data such as .css .js .flv. png .ico .gif .jpg etc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want nginx on windows?
from http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html:

> Version of nginx for Windows uses the native Win32 API (not the Cygwin
>   emulation layer). Only the select() connection processing method is
>   currently used, so high performance and scalability should not be
>   expected. Due to this and some other known issues version of nginx for
>   Windows is considered to be a ***beta*** version.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new location directive which points to your static files:

```
location ~* \.(css|js|png|ico|gif|jpg)$ { 
   root path/to/static/folder
}
```

As for FLV, you'll want to read the [HttpFlvModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFlvModule) article if you want to have seek. Otherwise, just add 'flv' into the extension pattern.